# Issue with storing a dictionary of list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm having a problem with my code that parses an input file (sample seen below) and stores information in a combination of lists/dictionaries.

I have a CSV file that has lines similar to this (they are Baseball stats):

```
Reyes,Jose,Mets,SS,681,191,36,12,12,57,.280
```

I am able to split up each field and properly store it in variables for now but the issue comes into play when I have to store the data in data structures.

I have to store each players stats and then subsequently store the players in a dict/list of each team they belong to.

My though process was similar to this:

```
DICT OF TEAMS (TEAM IS KEY, VALUE IS A DICT OF PLAYERS)
|
V
DICT OF PLAYERS (THEIR FULL NAME IS KEY, VALUE IS A LIST OF STATS)
|
V
LIST OF STATS (EVERY SINGLE STAT IS IN HERE)
```

Unfortunately, my stats list will fill up with info from the entire text file (essentially putting the text file in a list). I've tried clearing the table at the end of the while loop but it clears the list out completely even though I store it in the player dictionary.

Maybe someone can simplify my thoughts or tell me what I am doing wrong.

Heres my code for reference:

```
import sys
from collections import OrderedDict

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    filename = raw_input("No filename supplied. Please enter one now: ")
    print "Filename supplied. Running now."
else:
    print "Filename supplied. Running now."
    filename = sys.argv[-1]

#print "\n"

f = open(filename, "r")
l = f.readline()

lastName = ""       #0
firstName = ""      #1
teamName = ""       #2
position = ""       #3
atBats = ""         #4
baseHits = ""       #5
doubles = ""        #6
triples = ""        #7
homeruns = ""       #8
rbi = ""            #9
batingAvg = ""      #10

fullName = ""

teams = {}
players = {}
stats = []

while l:
    l = l.strip("\n")
    curCol = l.split(",")
    l = f.readline()

    lastName = curCol[0]
    firstName = curCol[1]
    teamName = curCol[2]
    position = curCol[3]
    atBats = curCol[4]
    baseHits = curCol[5]
    doubles = curCol[6]
    triples = curCol[7]
    homeruns = curCol[8]
    rbi = curCol[9]
    batingAvg = curCol[10]

    fullName = firstName + " " + lastName

    stats.append(lastName)
    stats.append(firstName)
    stats.append(teamName)
    stats.append(position)
    stats.append(atBats)
    stats.append(baseHits)
    stats.append(doubles)
    stats.append(triples)
    stats.append(homeruns)
    stats.append(rbi)
    stats.append(batingAvg)

    players[fullName] = stats

print players
```

Comment: take a look at the csv module.

Comment: _"their full name is key, value is a list of stats."_ What will you do when two players have the same name?

Comment: @Kevin I understand your point but I think it's quite unlikely that one team will have two players with the same name. If they do, then we wouldn't know which one the CSV is talking about anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have to clear your stats list at the end of each iteration.

```
while l:
    # ...
    stats = []
```

EDIT:

Ah, I understand your problem. It's because when you store the list in the dictionary and then clear it, it's clearing it in the dictionary as well.

I believe you could just make a copy of the list to store in the dictionary:

```
import copy
# ...
players[fullName] = copy.deepcopy(stats)
stats = []
```

EDIT 2:

Alternatively, I believe you could do this

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        firstName = line.split(",")[0]
        lastName = line.split(",")[1]
        players[firstName + " " + lastName] = line.split(",")[2:]
```

Comment: When I use the second method you listed (with deepcopy) I still get the same error if I call

    players['Jose Reyes']

Comment: Error meaning you get all of the statistics for every player when you query 'Jose Reyes'? Did you clear the list at the end of the while loop?

Comment: That did it! Totally forgot about that part. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @SlashTag No worries - if you want, you can make a copy of a list using `stats[:]` or `list(stats)` as well. `deepcopy` only serves to successfully copy lists of lists, or lists of objects. If it gets to be too slow look at the copy mechanism for optimizing.